# How add array of authors for unique user in database in Goland IDE?

Tags: sqlite, go, goland

I'm newbie in Go. I try to create simple database with sqlite3. I know that sqlite3 doesn't support arrays.

Database must send unique feed object for each unique user with array row of authors.

When user auth in system, it creates new record in table user:

```
id: 0 <- unique user id
phone: "+0 000"
feed: 0 <- feed id, same as user id
```

Than in table feed I have row's like:

```
id: 0 <- feed id, same as user id
authors: now it's integer and it's needs to be an array
isFave: bool <- is user like this author or not
```

So I also have author table where:

```
id: 0 <- unique author id
name: "name"
```

So for every unique user I want create unique feed where I store array of authors and I can for every record of authors set isFave or not.

How to do it?

I also make reference feed id from user table to feed table and make reference from feed author row to author table id. But I can't figure it out what to do further.

[image]